# Java: Drawing in 3D

Tags: java, graphics, 3d

I have been drawing in 2D for a while. I want to start expanding my experience with graphics by learning to draw in 3D. 
Is there 3D drawing potential with Graphics? 
What is a good resource for beginner 3D drawers? 
Finally, is Java even the best resource to draw in 3D?

Thanks guys, any and all input is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "drawing in 3D". Like you use a pencil and a paper, just in 3D? Or create 3D meshes? Voxel bodies? Use a 3D primitive based approach like when dealing with Persistence of Vision scenes?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wasn't sure exactly how to explain what I'm after. I would like to start with primitives (I think that may be the same as 3D meshes). After I get some of the lower level experience, I would like to start using models in 3D.

Comment: Ok, I was just not clear on this. @lynks is right, JOGL seems to be a good way to start with 3D and Java, though I would rather start with learning 3D basics before jumping into that headfirst, but I might be on a conservative side regarding this (I don't know what your knowledge level on this topic is, I'd start looking at [Shading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shading) and [3D projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection), not to mention [Transformation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) to have a strong foundation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is great for 3D. It has low-level bindings into [openGL](http://www.opengl.org/) in the form of [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/). There is a suitable tutorial for getting started [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~meesh/kmconroy/JOGLTutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be [Processing](https://www.processing.org/tutorials/p3d/).